# DataGridView change display type

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `BindingList` that I am displaying in a `DataGridView` my issue is that the one of the properties that I am displaying is a `byte[]` which I think that it is interpreting it as a bitmap (from the error message).

There are two solutions that I can see

1. What I want is to display it as a string so some sort of explicit cast?
2. I could make a new column that holds the password converted to a string. This seems a bit kludgy and I would prefer to not do it.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean with `byte[] hence it is interpreting it as a bitmap`. Can you please show a relevant part of your code to help us understand what you did and how you can get what you want (what is not too clear either)?

Comment: @varocarbas I think OP is referring to the default behavior of the `DataGridView` when auto populating columns (creates `DataGridViewImageColumn` for `byte[]` property type). Unfortunately there is no granular control on this, so you either get defaults, either create all columns manually

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for the clarification, I wasn't aware about this behaviour (haven't ever tried to display an array of bytes right away). In any case, what would you expect when trying to do such a thing? You might perform a conversion to another numeric type or to string if this is what you want. Alternatively, you might try to change the type of the column (although this might be problematic, if possible at all).

Comment: Do you have a control over the content of the binding list, i.e. if it is `BindingList<SomeClass>`, can you modify that class?

Comment: Yes but for other parts of my code would break if I switch it to a string

Answer (score 1):

Once you have control on the underlying data source class, you can add a special property used just for data binding (this way not breaking the existing code) and use attributes to control which one applies to UI.

Let assume your class is something like this

```
class MyClass
{
    // ....

    public byte[] Password { get; set; }
}
```

You can change it as follows

```
class MyClass
{
    // ....

    [Browsable(false)]
    public byte[] Password { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Password")]
    public string PasswordText
    {
        get { ... }
    }
}
```

and will get the desired behavior in `DataGridView` and similar controls.